# Is it possible to automatically add question numbers to Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I'm new to using Google Forms and have added all my questions.  Is it possible to automatically add question numbers or do I need to go back and manually write them at the beginning of each question?

Comment: Someone suggested that you can Ctrl+p and save the pdf file, and that the questions will be automatically numbered in the pdf file. But I think that this means you can print out the answers and the rows will be numbered - whereas the original question was about numbering the questions themselves on the Google Form.

Comment: @Japdeep I'm not sure what answer this is referring to, so I've moved the comment up here.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not possible to automatically add question numbers to Google Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to simply add a question number to the begining of each question.

For example:

> 1) What year were you born?

Then you can go to your response spread sheet and put a more "code" oriented column header, or even move the columns to match the order of the question.

For example in your responses spreadsheet:

Row 1, machine readable answers, or anything you'd like: **"foo, bar"**
Row 2, your actual questions from the form: **"I am Question Foo?, I am Question bar?"**
Row n, responses: **"..."**

Answer (score 0):

The Google Forms UI doesn't has an automatic question numbering feature, like pressing a numbered list format button, but this feature could be added by using Google Apps Script. Maybe someone already did for you, so take a look to the add-ons store before you write your own script. For further details see [Use add-ons and Google Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)